# Mysql is cutting texts after speicial charcters

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

When i try to insert `government-owned` using my php script below, it only insert `government`, when i use PHPmyAdmin, it works perfectly. is something wrong with my php script?

```
class database
  {
     private $config = array(
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'dbname'    => 'yelo'
        );


public function dbConnect(){

    $dbcnx = @mysql_connect($this->config['host'], $this->config['username'], $this->config['password'])
    or die("The site database appears to be down.");

    if ($this->config['dbname']!="" and !@mysql_select_db($this->config['dbname']))        
    die("The site database is unavailable.");

    return $dbcnx;
    }

}


$connDb = new database; 
$connDb->dbConnect(); 

// I thought this could eliminate the problem
$business_name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['business_name']);

$query = "INSERT INTO business SET biz_name = '$business_name'" 
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's the charset of your php script file? What's the database/table/field collation?

Comment: I set my collation 'utf8_general_ci' and charset 'utf-8', sorry, i should include it in the question.

Comment: Check the warning on the docs page, it is relevant: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: try `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` right after establishing the connection.

Comment: Check all those red warnings about `mysql_` functions, too. They are deprecated, you should think about switching to `mysqli` or `PDO`.